RabbitMq cluster operator and loadBalancerIP
I'm trying to get a RabbitMq Cluster configured with a load balancer IP (I know it's being deprecated at some point, but that's not apparently yet) and I'm having problems getting the service definition correct.
Here's what it starts with:
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-cluster
  namespace: rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 3
  rabbitmq:
    additionalConfig: |
      loopback_users.guest = false
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    loadBalancerIP: 10.191.2.17
    annotations:
      load-balancer/rabbitmq: "true"

If I run without the loadBalancerIP line in, the cluster starts fine, but not on the IP address I want it on.
With it in I'm getting the following error:
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "RabbitMq .yaml": RabbitmqCluster in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a RabbitmqCluster: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.service.loadBalancerIP".
Edit:
If it’s not possible then could I do something like place an nginx server in front of the ClusterIP? If so would someone be able to held with the appropriate yaml?

Seems not possible to specify your loadbalancerIP using this CRD. Here is the spec for the service part https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/blob/main/api/v1beta1/rabbitmqcluster_types.go#L412 only type, annotations and IPFamilyPolicy are possibles

@QuentinGeff : any suggestions on how to leverage IPFamilyPolicy to achieve this?

I recommend you to avoid declaring your service as part of your RabbitmqCluster manifest. It's optional as the default is : { type: "ClusterIP"}. You'll have a private ip associated by default, but then you could define your service explicitly the way you want targeting your rabbitmq pods : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service

So, you suggesting a separate service that targets the private ClusterIP via a selector? If so do I still keep my SSL config within Rabbit and allow the service to sit on top?

Yes exactly a selector in your service and define a corresponding label in your RabbitmqCluster.metadata.labels. Do not rely on the private ClusterIP that could change over the time. And the answer is yes for your ssl config, the alternative would be the have an ingress controller in front of your rabbit pods handling the TLS connection but I do not see any plus-value honestly

Thanks to the reply by @QuentinGeff, I was able to come up with the following service that does the trick:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-loadbalancer
  namespace: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.191.2.17
  ports:
    - name: amqps
      port: 5671
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5671
    - name: management-ui
      port: 15671
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 15671
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: RabbitMq-cluster

